# Git Bash, go back in folders

Tags: git-bash

Im doing a course of "ECMASCRIPT 6" and in the video the teacher is using the Git Bash console. i have to go back in the folders so i can go to the folder i want (im in C, i want to go to a folder in D) but using the command "cd.." or "cd..." doesn't work.

```
DanielaStornelli@DESKTOP-J408UN1 MINGW64 /c/Windows/system32
$ cd..
bash: cd..: command not found
```

i tried right clicking in the folder i want to go and selecting "Git Bash Here" as the teacher does in the video but i don't get that option. I also opened "Git Bash" as administrator just in case, but its the same problem.
This is the folder i want to go to:

```
D:\ES6
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What's your operating system? Windows? Try `cd /d/ES6`?

Comment: Btw it's `cd ..`, you need a whitespace between `cd` and `..`

Comment: ... unless there is an alias set up for `cd..`, of course.

Comment: Definitely not a git question. Removing the tag.

Comment: Is my answer helps you ?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov oh that was it, the space between cd and .. 
i can't believe that was the problem.. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is a space between the two "CD" and the two fullstops. I retried that and it worked..

**A Brief Theory**:

To go back to particular directory without pasting the entire directory simply input this command:
"cd"+".."
That is the normal Change directory command :"cd" plus two fullstops "..". This will simply go backspace the current directory and goes back to the previous directory.

An example if you had "C://Users"

After the command you would go to "C://"

Attached below is how I used it to go back to the previous working directory.

[Git Bash Example of Going back to the Previous Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYJjO.png)

If this also doesn't help consider searching other Gitbash commands e.g., pwd (Previous working Directory)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go to a certain file or directory you don't need to type it, just drag the file or directory to the bash window and the `path` of that file or directory will show up (in Windows, not sure about other operating systems), then just write in at the start of that path `cd`  (with space between the `cd` and the `path`) and you will enter that `path` in bash

Comment: nothing happened when i dragged the file, but the space between cd and .. did it, that was the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first enter "cd" normally and then "cd D:\ES6" paste this using shift and insert and then you will be transferred
to your desired directory

Comment: In Windows, the "cd" command works only inside a disk unity (C, D, E, etc.). It can be used to change the disk where you are. If you want to change the unity you are in, you have to type the letter of the unity, followed by a colon. Example: D: . After that, you can use the cd command to navigate to the desired folder.